# If $(h_2(k),m) = 1$ then $h_1(k)+ih_2(k) \bmod{m}$ is a permutation of $0,\ldots,m-1$

Tags: hash, hash-tables, hashing

The following question appears in [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (CLRS):

> Suppose that we use double hashing to resolve collisions; that is, we use the hash function $ h(k, i) = (h_1(k) + ih_2(k)) \bmod{m} $. Show that the probe sequence $\langle h(k, 0), h(k, 1), \dots , h(k, m - 1) \rangle$ is a permutation of the slot sequence $(0, 1, \dots , m-1)$ if and only if $h_2(k) $ is relatively prime to $m$. (Hint: See Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)).

Double hash function uses two hash functions, given that $h(k, i) = (h_i(k) + ih_2(k)) \bmod{m} $, such that integer $i$ is $i=0, \dots, m-1$ when we probe in case of collision, so we start first with $i=0$, if there is a collision, then $i=1$ and so on until we find an empty slot. The key $k$ is an integer.

**Attempt**: Relatively prime and co-prime is same thing. So if $h_2(k) $ is relatively prime to $m$, then $\gcd(h_2(k), m) = 1$. So, if $h_2(k)$ and $h_2(k)$ and $m$  are always co-prime to each other, we can see we always get a number between $h_2(k) \bmod{m}$ that is in slots $(0, \dots, m-1)$. If $h_2(k)$ is not relatively prime to $m$, then for the probe sequence $\langle h(k, 0), h(k, 1), \dots , h(k, m - 1)\rangle$, we might get two elements in the probe sequence that are identical to each other. This is how I approached it, so I am not sure how that will prove that $\langle h(k, 0), h(k, 1), \cdots , h(k, m - 1) \rangle$ is a permutation of $(0, 1, \dots , m-1)$ anyway.

Comment: let's consider only h2(k) * i part, and have a = h2(k). i is 0 ... m-1. a * i is m different values, we want to prove that a * i takes each of these values exactly once. Let's assume that it is not the case. Then there are i_1 and i_2 such that a * i_1 = a * i_2 = b mod  m, b is arbitrary value. But we know that if gcd(a, m) = 1 then linear congruence can have only one solution. So  a * i takes m different values -> thus all values between 0 and m - 1. If i understand correctly adding h1 will just rotate these values.

Comment: see here about linear congruence: http://www.math.niu.edu/~richard/Math420/lin_cong.pdf

Comment: @effenok. Thank you very much.

Comment: does it work? then i will post it as answer.

Comment: Thanks again effenok. I got the answer from @robjohn. So I appreciate your time. You interpretation is similar to the one I got. So I got the answer. Please no need to post it.

Comment: i think stackoverflow generally prefers having accepted answers to questions. but if @robjohn has a better answer, he should post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write your question more succinctly:

> Let $m \geq 1$ and $a,b$ be integers. The set $S = \{ a+ib \bmod{m} : 0 \leq i \leq m-1 \}$ consists of the integers $0,\ldots,m-1$ iff $b$ is relatively prime to $m$.

Note that $S$ consists of the integers $0,\ldots,m-1$ iff the values $a+ib \bmod{m}$ are all distinct.

Suppose first that $b$ is not relatively prime to $m$. This means that we can find $c > 1$ that divides both $b$ and $m$. It follows that $a \bmod{m} = a + (m/c)b \bmod{m}$, since $(m/c)b$ is a multiple of $m$. Since $1 \leq m/c \leq m-1$, this shows that $S$ contains fewer than $m$ distinct values.

Now suppose that $b$ is relatively prime to $m$. Assume, by way of contradiction, that not all values in $S$ are distinct, say $a+ib \bmod{m} = a+jb \bmod{m}$ for some $i < j$. Then $(j-i)b \bmod{m} = 0$, where $1 \leq j-i \leq m-1$. This means that $(j-i)b$ is a multiple of $m$. Since $b$ is relatively prime to $m$, this implies that $j-i$ is a multiple of $m$, which is impossible since $1 \leq j-i \leq m-1$.